# Hot reload in Dash does not automatically update

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

As announced [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-hot-reload/14177), Dash's hot reload is supposed to be automatically activated when `debug=True`. However, that is not working for me. I even tried explicitly setting `dev_tools_hot_reload=True`. 
I save the code file from the IDE but I see no changes on the web interface thereafter.
 Even reloading the page makes no difference. I have to stop the server and re-run the script. 
What can be the issue?

**Edit** 
I am working with VSCode & running the script from the windows powershell (outside the VSCode terminal). 
Installing a new version from conda-forge didn't work.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: If you are using Jupiter read about hot reloading in Jupyter here: https://medium.com/plotly/introducing-jupyterdash-811f1f57c02e

Comment: I am using both Jupyter and Visual Studio Code. Sure I'll check the link for Jupyter but why is this also the case @VSC?

Comment: In VS code launch in terminal, not in Python Interactive Mode. In terminal it works for me but fails in Python Interactive Mode.

Comment: Yeah, I am actually running it from terminal but still...

Comment: If you installed dash from Anaconda it has old version of Dash and that may be a problem. Try to install new version from conda-forge. Just create new conda environment and try conda-forge version of Dash there.

Comment: Ok will try but on the other hand why shouldn't a simple dash update work (I tried and it updated some stuff but the problem persists)?

Answer (score 4):

I personally could not find a satisfactory answers on either Dash docs or Dash forum. It seems like in every post you are given different instructions on how to implement hot-reloading with the refrain "it's built in and should just work."
So here is anecdotical solution how it worked for me:

- PyCharmPro 2020.1.4
- Chrome 84.0.4147.105

**file.py:**

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
# Dash code
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run_server(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

If everything is working, then the tab name should change to:

[image]

And the page would auto-reload within about 2 seconds after hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

**pip freeze**

- dash==1.14.0
- dash-core-components==1.10.2
- dash-html-components==1.0.3
- dash-renderer==1.6.0
- dash-table==4.9.0
- Flask==1.1.2

Comment: This apparently does not work with dash 1.1.7.0.